# Unable to retrieve username while parsing with python

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-requests

below is my code snippet:

```
#from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

session = requests.Session()

payload = {'user': 'user@comcast.net',
          'passwd': 'password'}

s = session.post("https://login.xfinity.com/", data=payload)

s = session.get('https://customer.xfinity.com/#/?CMP=ILC_signin_myxfinity_re')

#soup = BeautifulSoup(s.text, 'html.parser')
print(s.text)
```

Once I execute the above code, I am trying to retrieve the user name from s.text. But it does not carry the username that appears when I log on to the xfinity account.

I am able to see the user name only when I manually login to account using the browser. How can I retrieve all the info that I need? 
PS: 
1. I did try the library "webbot". But that is not my preference to use in my code. I am open to use libraries like "requests".
2. I have tried with other websites as well, I have encountered the same error

Comment: "*I did try the library "webbot". But that is not my preference to use in my code. I am open to use libraries like "requests".*" Why are you arbitrarily limiting the size of your toolkit? If `webbot` or something similar works for your purposes, why would you exclude it? Have you considered that `requests` crafts a request to which the server returns a different page than what you're setting when you "*manually login to account using the browser*"?

Comment: Hi, based on the samples that I have tried for webbot. Webbot literally initiated a chrome browser to lunch the URL & connect to the app. Which is not recommended in my workplace. Code is below : 
from webbot import Browser 
web = Browser()
web.go_to('https://login.xfinity.com/') 
# web.click('Sign in')
web.type('user@comcast.net' , into='user')
# web.click('NEXT' , tag='span')
web.type('PASS' , into='Password' , id='passwordId') # specific selection
web.click('Sign In' , tag='span') # you are logged in ^_^

Comment: Why is it "*not recommended in [your] workplace*"? This seems like an arbitrary restriction at best. Besides, whatever checks or interface manipulations the target site is performing using JavaScript won't be possible using just `requests`. There is `requests_html`, but even then it's not likely whatever security mechanisms the target site is implementing would allow such behavior. A good portion of enterprise websites look for browser-like fingerprints to eliminate automations/bots exactly like yours to limit the amount of traffic from these types of solutions (malicious or otherwise).

Comment: Understand. In that case, I may need to work as an exception for this requirement. Below are the constraints, constraint 1 is easy to over come with exception approval. But what about the constraint 2?

Answer to your question on why we may not prefer using the webbot - 
1.just to keep the application lighter. Belief is that launching the browser is a "heavy" solution. 
2.the app that I need to scrape is a legacy app & is not compatible with chrome & I believe webbot initiates on chrome browser

Answer (score 0):

Considering my web app is not compatible in any browser other than IE, I could not find a solution to achieve this at this point.